# node.js native extension vs. pure js module

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a new node.js component. I write it from scratch - no existing assets to reuse. What are some of the considerations for building a native extension vs. a pure js module?

Comment: One obvious consideration would be portability. It's much easier to make something that runs on both Linux/Mac and Windows if you use pure JavaScript.

Comment: the question is tagged node.js, but is blatantly unrelated to it.  the gist of the question is "what are some considerations for going native vs. using a scripting language?", and that's very general, and likely has 35 duplicates on stackoverflow.com alone.  be more specific and i'll be happy to undo the vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to write pure js modules. First they are a lot easier to write and maintain. Second they are cross-platform. Third, which I think is also pretty important you will probably have no memory leaks when you write your extensions in pure javascript.

When you have finished the pure javascript implementation and the performance is desired/OK I don't think you should write native extension. Only try this when the performance is subpar.

Also I believe they are changing the complete infrastructure to write native extension and will use [gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) instead?